# Dealing with a null column in LINQ while concatenate to a string

Tags: c#, linq, null, string-concatenation

I'm trying to fetch person details, where middle name is missing some times, in my application. I'm trying with like this:

`contactTable.Select(c => c.Title + " " + c.FirstName).ToList();`

But whenever the title column remains null in DB, it returns empty for that entry. I want some kind of like:

`contactTable.Select(c => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Title) ? "" : c.Title + " ") + c.FirstName).ToList();`

Is this possible in one linq statement? Thanks in advance.

This is possible and the complete answer is including the nullable MiddleName:

```
contactDetails = contactTable.Select(c =>
            ((c.Title ?? "") + " " + c.FirstName).Trim() + " " + ((c.MiddleName ?? "") + " " + c.LastName).Trim()).ToList();
```

See the double use of `Trim()`.

Comment: code updated ....applied trim so there will be no space if title is not there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of : [?? Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

try this below code

```
contactTable.Select(c => ( (( c.Title ?? "") + " "  + c.FirstName).Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: But this leaves one space if there is no title.

Comment: @Arnab Das - code updated ....applied trim so there will be no space if title is not there

Comment: Why check c.Title when using trim, simply concat values and trim

Comment: @ArnabDas you can use ? operator so code can be change to  (c => c.Title ?? "" + (c.FirstName != null ? " " + c.FirstName : "") )